# Selecting columns from different entities

Tags: swift, core-data

I don't know whether I should be drawing parallels, but unfortunately, that's the only way I can express my issue.
In SQL, suppose we have two tables:

1. Employee with columns Employee ID, Employee Name, Dept. ID
2. Deptartment with columns Dept. ID, Dept Name

The Dept ID. in the Employee table is a foreign key with that in the Department table.

Now suppose I want to fetch the following columns:
Employee ID, Employee Name, Department Name

using a SQL such as:

```
SELECT A.EMPLOYEE_ID, A.EMPLOYEE_NAME, B.DEPT_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEE A, DEPARTMENT B
WHERE A.DEPT_ID = B.DEPT_ID
```

How would one do this using Core Data in Swift? I guess I'm getting confused by only seeing references to 
`NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName)`
where the entityName refers to a single entity (table in relational DB lingo)

I'd really appreciate any pointers or examples that can help me clear my doubts.

Thanks

Comment: I guess I found a tip from the Apple Documentation...Using Pre-fetching (relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching)...infact, they cite the same Employee Department example, although in O/C

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible to create a fetch request that is equivalent to your SQL query.  More complex queries can be difficult if not impossible to achieve with a single fetch request.  But I recommend trying NOT to draw parallels between CoreData and SQL, at least until you have got to grips with how it works.

To take your example, in the CoreData view of the world, `Employee` would be an entity with a relationship to another entity, `Department`.  A fetch request based on the `Employee` entity will return an array of `Employee` objects, and (assuming you create subclasses of NSManagedObject for each entity) you can access the attributes with simple dot notation:

```
let employeeName = myEmployeeObject.employeeName
```

But you can use the same notation to traverse relationships equally easily:

```
let departmentName = myEmployeeObject.department.departmentName
```

You don't need to worry about joins, etc; CoreData handles that for you.

Now, suppose you try to do it "the SQL way".  You can construct a fetch request based on the Employee entity, but specify "properties to fetch" which likewise traverse the relationship:

```
let fetch = NSFetchRequest(entity:"Employee")
fetch.propertiesToFetch = ["employeeID", "employeeName", "department.departmentName"]
```

For this to work, you would need to specify the "resultType" for the fetch request to be DictionaryResultType:

```
fetch.resultType = .DictionaryResultType
```

The results from this query would be an array of dictionaries containing the relevant keys and values.  But the link with the underlying objects is lost.  If you subsequently want to access any details from the relevant `Department` (or even the `Employee`), you would have to run a new fetch to get the object itself.